# Rails/Yarn: Following tutorial leaves package.json file in my project. Should I get rid of this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, package.json

While trying to learn how to use `yarn` with `rails` a tutorial I was following, instructed me to run `yarn init` in my project, creating what seems like a useless `package.json` file, since this isn't going to be a `yarn` package but a `ruby`/`rails` application.

Here is the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "myapplication",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0"
  }
}
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what this file is for but it seems more like a `*.gemspec` type file for a javascript package than an important file for a Rails application. I understand the importance of having `yarn.lock` included in `git` but I don't see why I need `package.json`. Can I add it to `.gitignore` or even delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `yarn.lock` file gets generated by `yarn` after resolving and installing the dependencies defined in `package.json`. Thus, you should check in this file.

Unlike Ruby, Node uses the same file to define a package and to define a projects dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is much appreciated.